# Como criar um aquivo.h?

Tags: c, c++

Para que serve um `arquivo.h` e que melhoria ele traz para o programa em C++?

Comment: Seria melhor esclarecer melhor o que você quer saber porque é do mesmo jeito que se faz qualquer outro arquivo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Os arquivos com extensão `.h` ou `.hpp` como gostam alguns para diferenciar dos arquivos de cabeçalho do C, costumam ser usados para colocar código necessário para compilação de outras partes de uma aplicação.

Quando criamos uma aplicação, ou mesmo uma biblioteca, algumas informações são necessárias para compilar. Alguns exemplos são as classes, as estruturas, as constantes estáticas e a declaração das funções (os chamados protótipos). No caso das classes e estruturas estamos falando de diversos elementos, incluindo aí assinatura dos métodos.

Basicamente o que não é necessário para a compilação são os algoritmos, ou seja o código dentro doas funções ou métodos. Estes podem ser compilados para código binário e não são mais necessários para o processo de compilação. Pelo menos na maior parte dos casos.

Ainda existem os casos onde se deseja fazer o *inline* do código ou ele for gabaritado (*template*).

Este arquivo é uma forma de organizar o código e facilitar a inclusão deste código em outros arquivos.

Ao contrário do que alguns possam pensar, este arquivo tem código normal que bem poderia estar em um arquivo `.cpp`. É claro que se todas estas declarações citadas estiverem no arquivo `.cpp` perde-se flexibilidade. Fica complicado usar o seu conteúdo em outro lugar.

Um arquivo que inclua um `.hpp` após pré-processado passar ter o conteúdo do `.hpp` como sempre estivesse escrito nele. Ou seja, o arquivo é como se fosse copiado para o arquivo que vai ser compilado.

Então no arquivo `.cpp` você tem a **definição** dos algoritmos e no `.hpp` você tem a declaração. Note que isto é uma convenção universalmente adotada mas nada impede de fazer de um jeito diferente. Só não existe motivo para inventar outro jeito. Com ele você pode ter ganhos no tempo de compilação, além de organizar melhor o que estrutura de dados e o que é algoritmo.

Se você tiver um arquivo `.cpp` assim:

```
void teste();

void main() {
    teste();
}

void teste() {
    printf("teste");
```

Você ou só pode usar a função `teste()` neste arquivo ou então precisa incluir o código junto, o que pode complicar por existir o `main()`, além de gastar tempo com a compilação de algo que já deve estar compilado. Claro que é possível guardar (`#ifdef`) o trecho para não incluir o que não precisa, mas pode acabar complicado o compilação normal do arquivo e coloca coisa no arquivo que não são necessárias para ele.

Se separar assim no `teste.hpp`:

```
void teste();
```

E o `main.cpp` ficando assim:

```
void main() {
    teste();
}

void teste() {
    printf("teste");
```

Você pode usar a função `teste()` em qualquer outro lugar. Vamos imaginar que crie um novo arquivo `.cpp` assim:

```
#include "teste.hpp"
void funcao() {
    teste();
}
```

Isto funciona porque a declaração da função será inclusa no arquivo, mesmo que o código efetivo da função não seja. Após o pré-processamento este código ficará:

```
void teste();
void funcao() {
    teste();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Header.h).

Answer (score 4):

Amigo, o arquivo .h é um cabeçalho, um arquivo de configuração, lá você pode definir constantes, incluir bibliotecas, coisas que serão usadas no seu main (programa principal). Você cria um .h e inclui no seu programa principal.

Separando tais funcionalidades, você tem maior manutenibilidade em seu código fonte, por exemplo se quiser usar outra biblioteca é só inseri-la no .h e automaticamente seu programa a usará,  e também poderá usar o mesmo .h em outros programas.

Espero ter ajudado.