# Como importar funções de outro arquivo em C?

Tags: c, header

Em Java caso criemos outras classes, como por exemplo: `classe1` e `classe2`, se eu quiser chamar a `classe1` dentro da `classe2` (pois eles estão em arquivos separados) eu utilizo `import classe1`.

Fiz este código em C, ele é um jogo da velha que tenho que utilizar alguns recursos de inteligência computacional. Eu sempre gosto de separar meus códigos com regras de negócios (rg) e ui (usuário interface) ou seja, "palavras, perguntas" vão em um "arquivo" e o "código" vai em outro "arquivo".

Como eu faço para chamar outro arquivo dentro de outro arquivo em C, igual eu citei em Java? Para poder utilizar funções de outros arquivos...

[image: Código em C]

Comment: C não tem classes. Não tem hierarquia alguma acima. Não tem perguntas ali. Não regra de negócio descrita. Tudo o que está descrito está sem sentido e nessa forma não tem como responder essa pergunta. Precisa colocar algo mais contextualizado, mostrar realmente o que está fazendo, e qual o problema que quer resolver.

Comment: È porque eu estou começando agora o código... O código é para fazer um jogo de valha utilizando Inteligência Computacional. Eu sei que C não tem classes, eu digo chamar os "arquivos.c" no arquivo "main.c". No caso a pergunta ali é "  //PAINEL - MENU
    printf("\nEscolha:");
    printf("\n(1)- Player x Player");
    printf("\n(2)- Player x PC");
    printf("\n(3)- PC x PC");"  ...... Eu não quero colocar o scanf no main.c, eu quero criar um outro "arquivo.c" colocar o código dentro, só que o main.c irá chamar esse arquivo para exibir as escolhas.

Comment: Acho melhor então postar uma pergunta quando tiver com algo mais concreto e claro, na forma atual não tem como responder a pergunta.

Comment: Eu melhorei a pergunta @bigown , compreende agora?

Comment: Melhorou. Prefira colocar o código para facilitar para os outros que vão te responder. Imagens não são úteis. Na verdade seria bom colocar o código do outro arquivo também, indicando isso claramente.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Ao contrário do Java em C a declaração costuma ficar separada da definição das funções. É comum que a definição vá em um arquivo `.c` e a declaração fique em um arquivo chamado de cabeçalho `.h`. Mas isso não é obrigatório.

Ao contrário do que muita gente acredita o protótipo (declaração da função) é necessária apenas quando vai usar em arquivo externo - a intenção aqui - ou quando há referências cíclicas entre funções. O jeito usado na pergunta é totalmente descartável se mudar a ordem das funções.

Quando vai usar funções de outro arquivo o comum é usar o `#include` desse `.h` para incluir as definições e o compilador saber como tratar aquilo.

Todos os códigos, em geral `.c` precisam ser compilados. Isso é feito manualmente. Eles também precisam ser *linkados* juntos de alguma forma, seja durante a compilação ou posteriormente, quando já tem algo pré-compilado.

A pergunta não dá informações suficientes para dar uma resposta mais detalhada, mas seria basicamente o que já fez com componentes da linguagem:

```
#include <seuOutroArquivo.h>
```

É claro que nem sempre precisa fazer isso. Depende do contexto, do caso concreto que está fazendo. Para decidir o jeito certo tem que aprender o todo, entender a filosofia da linguagem.

Nesse arquivo teria algo assim (vou chutar já que a pergunta não ajuda):

```
int algumaRegraDeNegocio(int);
```

E aí em um arquivo `.c` teria algo assim:

```
int algumaRegraDeNegocio(int valor) {
    //faz alguma coisa aqui
    return 1;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/ExempleInclusde.c).

Obviamente isso é uma enorme simplificação.

Para entender melhor o [funcionamento do *header*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76782/101).

Veja: [Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101)

Note que há uma distância muito grande entre Java e C. Se tentar reproduzir em C o que fazia em Java vai dar muito errado. Digo isso porque parece que está tentando usar a filosofia de uma na outra.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui temos um exemplo do arquivo exemplo.c que voce ira compilar (/home/andre/workspace/c/exemplo.c)

```
#include </home/andre/workspace/c/andruida.c>
int main(){
printa(100);
printo();
return 0;
}
```

Aqui embaixo um arquivo descrito no include do arquivo acima
(/home/andre/workspace/c/andruida.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printa(int l){
    while (l--)printf("PRINTA\t");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int printo(){
    printf("\n\n\nPRINTO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Como eu uso gcc no shell:

```
gcc -o exemplo exemplo.c
```

Veja que nem precisei mencionar o andruida.h

Comment: Este exemplo não está bom porque de maneira geral não coloca código executável em arquivos .h.

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo simples de organização de arquivos de um projeto na linguagem C.
(Os nomes das funções são apenas ilustrativos, e não um esquema a ser seguido!)

Arquivo ..../jogo/main.c

```
#include "rg/rg.h" // regras de negocios
#include "ui/ui.h" // interface com usuario

// constantes visiveis apenas neste arquivo fonte
enum { N_THINGS = 100, N_OTHER_THINGS = 42 };

// funcoes locais a este arquivo fonte
static void funcLocal_01(void);
static void funcLocal_02(void);

// variaveis globais visiveis apenas neste arquivo fonte
static int nThings;
static char nameThings[N_THINGS];

int main(void)
{
   nThings = 10;
   abcd = 0; // esta' no "modulo" rg

   if (xyz == 123) // esta' no "modulo" ui
   {
      // bla bla bla
      // bla bla bla
   }

   func_ui_001();
   func_rg_xyz();

   funcLocal_01();

   func_rg_xxx();
   func_ui_zzz();

   funcLocal_02();
}

void funcLocal_01(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   // bla bla bla
}

void funcLocal_02(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   // bla bla bla
}
```

Arquivo ..../jogo/rg/rg.h

```
extern int abcd;

extern void func_rg_xyz(void);
extern void func_rg_xxx(void);
```

Arquivo ..../jogo/rg/rg.c

```
// variavel exportada
int abcd = 1;

// variaveis locais a este arquivo fonte
static int xyz;
static char array[54];

// funcoes locais este arquivo fonte
static void func1(void);
static void func2(void);

void func_rg_xyz(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   func1();
   // bla bla bla
}

void func_rg_xxx(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   func2();
   // bla bla bla
}

void func1(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   // bla bla bla
}

void func2(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   // bla bla bla
}
```

Arquivo ..../jogo/ui/ui.h

```
extern int xyz;

extern void func_ui_001(void);
extern void func_ui_zzz(void);
```

Arquivo ..../jogo/ui/ui.c

```
int xyz = 49;

void func_ui_001(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   // bla bla bla
}

void func_ui_zzz(void)
{
   // bla bla bla
   // bla bla bla
}
```