# Existe alguma diferença entre as maneiras de declarar classes em C++?

Tags: c++

Desde que comecei a aprender C++ sempre fiz algo como:

**classe.h**

```
#ifndef CLASSE_H
#define CLASSE_H

class OutraClasse;

class Classe
{
   public:
      Classe();
      void foo(OutraClasse *bar);
};

#endif
```

E aqui eu declaro os métodos, construtor e outras coisas **classe.cpp**:

```
#include "classe.h"
#include <OutraClasse>

Classe::Classe()
{
    //Algo aqui
}

void Classe::foo(OutraClasse *foo) {
    //Algo aqui
}
```

Mas noto que eventualmente algumas classe são escritas somente no `.h` assim:

```
#ifndef CLASSE_H
#define CLASSE_H

#include <OutraClasse>

class Classe : public OutraClasse
{
   public:
       Classe() {
           //Algo aqui
       }

       void foo(OutraClasse *bar) {
           //Algo aqui
       }
};

#endif
```

O **main.cpp** ficaria algo como em ambos:

```
#include "classe.h"
#include <OutraClasse>

int main()
{
    OutraClasse outra;

    Classe foobar;
    foobar.foo(&outra);
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber se isso influencia na compilação ou pós-compilação, por exemplo execução, isso devido a ordem de declaração dos *headers*, quero dizer, se entendi bem o primeiro exemplo que citei funciona muito só chamaria `OutraClasse` quando `foobar` for usado, no segundo exemplo ele seria chamado a todo momento.

Existe alguma diferença para compilação, execução ou performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Colocar tudo no *header*

A grande vantagem é permitir melhores otimizações. Se deseja que as implementações sejam *inline* tem que fazer isso. O mesmo vale para o uso de *templates* que sempre há um *inline* do gabarito, ele nunca é resolvido em tempo de execução. Falo disso em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87884/101).

O fato de ser *inline* obriga recompilar todos consumidores todas as vezes que mudar algo na classe. Isso é bom ou ruim dependendo do que deseja.

Tem uma desvantagem clara: todo o código da classe sempre terá que ser recompilado quando esta classe for usada (até é possível ter algum *cache* que ajuda). Há o custo de compilação maior nesse caso.

Se a otimização for feita não haverá indireção alguma. A performance tende a ser ligeiramente melhor. Isso costuma fazer sentido em códigos que precisam de alta performance. Não ajuda muito em GUI, por exemplo.

## Ter a implementação em arquivo separado

A grande vantagem é não ter que ficar compilando o algoritmo toda vez que usa, ele fica separado da declaração. Em compensação terá que recompilar o arquivo de algoritmo sempre que alterá-lo para o resto do código enxergar. Se esquecer de fazer isso, em tese tudo vai funcionar, mas acessará a versão antiga, que não é o que deseja, pode passar desapercebido.

A vantagem não é só o custo da compilação reduzido, mas tem uma semântica diferente nas modificações do código. Ao mesmo tempo que é uma desvantagem ter que recompilar a implementação para os consumidores poderem ver, os consumidores não precisam estar cientes da mudança na implementação. Pode recompilar a classe sem exigir recompilação dos seus consumidores, desde que a API permaneça a mesma. A API é o que está no cabeçalho.

Esses códigos não podem ser otimizados por *inline* nos locais de seu uso. Sempre haverá uma indireção, como toda função não linearizada.

Essa é a opção mais comum na maioria dos casos, mas a outra é bem usada também. Tem que dominar bem essas implicações para fazer a escolha certa, mas na dúvida o padrão é essa, todo mundo está bem acostumado com ela (não estou dizendo que é a melhor sempre, apenas que é a mais aceitável quando não se sabe o que fazer e a outra não seja obrigatória).

Tem mais uma [pergunta que pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76782/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Métodos definidos na declaração da classe são automaticamente considerados "inline" pelo compilador.

O compilador poder gerar código "inline" para esses métodos, isto é, não é criada uma função que encapsula esse código, e em cada chamado do método o código é copiado no lugar da chamada do método, ao invés de efetivamente ser feita uma chamada ao método. Efetivamente uma função inline é como se fosse uma macro inteligente.

Em princípio o compilador só cria código inline para funcões muito pequenas, mas isto fica a total critério do compilador, que pode eventualmente simplesmente desconsiderar essa possibilidade, e realmente criar funções para implementar todos os métodos inline.

```
class Classe : public OutraClasse
{
   public:
   Classe() {
       //Algo aqui
   }

   void foo(OutraClasse *bar) {
       //Algo aqui
   }
};
```