# Sobre __forceinline e __inline

Tags: c++, inline

Qual é a diferença entre utilizar `__forceinline` ou `__inline`? E pode utilizar `__forceinline` ou `__inline` em funções grandes?

Exemplo:

```
__forceinline void funcao1(void)
{
    cout << "Funcao 1" << endl;
}

__inline void funcao2(void)
{
   cout << "Funcao 2" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Lembrando que `__forceinline` e `__inline` são especificos dos compiladores da Microsoft e não fazem parte do padrão `C98`. Somente a palavra-chave `inline` faz parte do padrão `C98` e `C++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas instruções indicam para o compilador que você deseja que a função seja linearizada, ou seja, que ela no lugar de chamá-la o código dela seja colocado onde tinha uma chamada economizando alguns bytes e processamento já que não é mais necessário ter o [cabeçalho e rodapé da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101) e em alguns casos não precisa mais copiar dados do argumento para o parâmetro.

`inline` é padrão do C++ e é um dica para que o compilador considere fazer esta otimização ali. Não que ele não faça se não tiver estas palavra-chave, ele pode fazer se achar que compensa otimizar, mesmo sem nada escrito. Instruindo assim pode aumentar a chance, mas depende do compilador, nada garante. Naga garante que a otimização seja feita, o compilador pode recursar se ele achar que não compensa.

`__inline` é o mesmo mas é uma extensão do compilador da Microsoft. A forma exata que o compilador trata depende só dele.

`__forceinline` é só uma indicação que você quer mesmo que a otimização seja feita, então a chance é grade de ocorrer, mas também não é garantido. Se for muito claramente ruim o compilador não faz.

Poder usar em funções grandes pode, mas não é recomendado e é provável que o compilador ignore. Se não sabe se realmente será útil, não use, é um recurso bem avançado.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160).

Relacionadas:

- [Quando usar "inline"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101)
- [Qual é a finalidade do uso de funções inline na linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110886/101)
- [Implementação de classes no próprio header](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87883/101)
- [Existe alguma diferença entre as maneiras de declarar classes em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156907/101)
- [Qual o custo de chamar muitas funções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184411/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, foi extremante clara a sua explicação, agora finalmente eu entendi o porque algumas funções minha gerava um erro na hora de compilar.