# Uma função inline pode ter valor de retorno?

Tags: c++, funções, inline

Eu gostaria de saber se uma função inline pode ter valor de retorno e se ela **continuará funcionando como uma função *inline***, pois pelo que li em [Inline do GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/) se uma função tem retorno o compilador pode ignorar:

> Remember, inlining is only a request to the compiler, not a command. Compiler can ignore the request for inlining. Compiler may not perform inlining in such circumstances like:

> 4. If a function return type is other than void, and the return statement doesn’t exist in function body.

Agora como neste exemplo:

```cpp
inline unsigned int TamMatriz(int& matriz)
    {
        return sizeof matriz / sizeof matriz[0];
    }
```

Após passar pelo compilador, ele vai ignorar o `inline` ou a função vai passar a ser uma função *inline*? E nesse exemplo a única maneira que eu vejo para não ter o `return` é se eu passar outra variável como referencia, mas eu gostaria de poder fazer isso:

```cpp
unsigned int TamanhoMatriz = TamMatriz(OutraMatriz);
```

Comment: Algum problema com a resposta para retirar a aceitação?

Answer (score 2):

Não tem como saber se vai ignorar o `ìnline` porque depende do compilador, para qual plataforma está sendo compilado e mesmo que possa dizer se vai nesse exemplo um pequeno detalhe diferente no código pode mudar a estratégia, **o compilador é livre para fazer o que quiser** da forma que ele achar, leia mais em [Sobre __forceinline e __inline](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241534/101).

Então não existe "função *inline*", existe função que você deu uma **dica** para o compilador fazer isso. Na verdade mesmo sem o *inline* é muito provável que seja feito em algo tão simples, quase sempre este qualificador é desnecessário porque, ou faria de qualquer jeito ou não fará mesmo tendo ele.

Eu acho bem possível que seja feito no exemplo citado, inclusive não cai no caso que foi exemplificado do que pode ser ignorado.

O que foi dito no site citado é que uma função mal formada pode não ter essa otimização, afinal se você disse que deve ter um retorno e não faz isso, em muitas linguagens nem compilaria, porém C pode deixar porque pode ser algum truque do programador, mas daí a linearizar algo esquisito já fica mais complicado, é um risco para o compilador.

Como adendo final:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu fiz essa pergunta com o objetivo de saber se uma função com retorno pode ser "inline" pois eu realmente não tinha entendido o site e nesse caso eu queria que a função fosse "inline" para poder evitar o "call overhead" da chamada de funções.

Comment: Fazendo alguns testes verificando o assembly, parece que confirma o que você disse, mesmo sem o inline, o compilator pode está fazendo uma otimização.

Comment: (Agora eu aprendi) e gostaria de adicionar que olhado o assembly eu poso ter certeza se a função foi ou não "linearizada" (não sei se esse é o nome correto), caso haja uma chamada `call` no assembly uma função foi chamada e como consequência ela não foi 'lineralizada".