# Utilizar ficheiros hpp c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Boas,
eu estou a realizar um projeto para a escola, e a certa altura percebi que tinha de dividir o trabalho em ficheiros(pois estava a ficar confuso para encontrar os procedimentos), mas não estou a conseguir dividi-lo, acredito que não esteja a usar os ficheiros hpp bem, pois nunca os dei.
Agradeço ajuda a corrigir o código.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "introduzir.hpp"
#include "mostrar.hpp"
#include "eliminar.hpp"
#include "ordenar.hpp"
#include "classe.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
unsigned int microseconds;
int op;

//segunda lista
copiar_lista(){
    struct info *p=NULL;
    struct info *q=NULL;
    p=lista;
    while(p!=NULL){
        q=(struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
            q->tarefa[i]=' ';
            q->tarefa[i]=p->tarefa[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        q->id[i]=' ';
            q->id[i]=p->id[i];
        }
        q->nivel=p->nivel;
        q->next=lista2;
        lista2=q;
        p=p->next;
    }
}

//menu e switch para ordenar
escolha_ordenar(){
    copiar_lista();
    switch(op){
        case 1:{
            recentes();
            eliminar();
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            listar();
            system("pause");
            eliminar();
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            break;
        }
    }
}
menu_ordenar(){
    cout<<"1 - Mais recentes\n";
    cout<<"2 - Mais antigos\n";
    cout<<"3 - Prioridade Maior\n";
    cout<<"4 - Prioridade Menor\n";
    cin>>op;
    escolha_ordenar();
}

//menu e switch das escolhas
escolha(){
    switch(op){
        case 1:{
            introduzir();
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            int esc;
            listar();
            cout<<"0 - Sair";
            cin>>esc;
            if(esc==0){
            system("cls");
            return 0;}
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            eliminar();
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            menu_ordenar();
            break;
        }
        case 0:{
            cout<<"Obrigado por utilizar este programa!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
menu(){
    cout<<"1 - Introduzir\n";
    cout<<"2 - Listar\n";
    cout<<"3 - Eliminar\n";
    cout<<"4 - Ordenar\n";
    cout<<"0 - Sair\n";
    cin>>op;
    escolha();
}

//main
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    system("color 0e");
    do{
        menu();
        system("cls");
    }while(op!=0);
    system("pause");
}
```

introduzir.hpp

```
#ifndef INTRODUZIR_HPP
#define INTRODUZIR_HPP
#include "classe.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

introduzir(){
    struct info *p;
    p=(struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    cout<<"Introduza o ID: ";
    _flushall();
    cin.getline(p->id,50);
    cout<<"Introduza a tarefa: ";
    _flushall();
    cin.getline(p->tarefa,50);
    do{
    cout<<"Introduza o nível de prioridade(1-5): ";
    _flushall();
    cin>>p->nivel;
}while(p->nivel<1||p->nivel>5);
p->next=lista;
lista=p;
}
#endif
```

mostar.hpp

```
#ifndef MOSTRAR_HPP
#define MOSTRAR_HPP
#include "classe.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
listar(){
    struct info *p;
    p=lista;
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<<"ID: "<<p->id<<endl;
        cout<<"Tarefa: "<<p->tarefa<<endl;
        cout<<"Nível: "<<p->nivel<<endl;
        p=p->next;
    }
}
mostrar(){
    struct info *p;
    p=lista2;
    while(p!=NULL){
    cout<<"ID: "<<p->id<<endl;
        cout<<"Tarefa: "<<p->tarefa<<endl;
        cout<<"Nível: "<<p->nivel<<endl;
        p=p->next;
    }

}
#endif
```

eliminar.hpp

```
#idndef ELIMINAR_HPP
#define ELIMINAR_HPP
#include "classe.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

eliminar(){
    struct info *p;
    p=lista;

    while(p!=NULL){
        lista=p->next;
        free(p);
        p=lista;
    }
}
#endif
```

ordenar.hpp

```
#ifndef ORDENAR_HPP
#define ORDENAR_HPP
#include "classe.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
recentes(){
    copiar_lista();
    struct info *p;
    p=lista2;
    struct info *prev=NULL;
    struct info *next=NULL;
    while(p!=NULL){
        next=p->next;
        p->next=prev;
        prev=p;
        p=next;
    }
    lista2=prev;
    mostrar();
}
#endif
```

classe.hpp

```
#ifndef CLASSE_HPP
#define CLASSE_HPP
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <unistd.h>


struct info{
    char tarefa[50],id[50];
    int nivel;  
    struct info *next;
};
struct info *lista=NULL;
struct info *head_ref=NULL;
struct info *lista2=NULL;
#endif
```

Comment: Você compreende que o ciclo de vida de um código C++ é: pré-compilar, transformar em arquivo objeto/arquivo `.o`/arquivo `.obj`, e só então linkar todos os arquivos objetos em um executável na fase denominada de linkedição?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pode entrar para fazer *inline* :) Mas o código aí não precisa, o uso é errado mesmo. Na verdade o código tem inúmeros problemas, inclusive ele é essencialmente C.

Comment: @Maniero, super simplifiquei. E o fiz erroneamente. Inclusive para usar classes/funções com `template` é necessário por no _header_ o código. Tentar por em termos corretos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Até porque com `template` é um *inlinining*. Falei mais pra não ficar pendurado para leigos, eu entendi a simplificação, eu faço isso também.

Comment: Essa leitura vai lhe dar uma boa noção do que se deve entrar no arquivo de cabeçalho/.hpp: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76787/64969; uma dica: normalmente você coloca apenas declarações, evita-se colocar implementação de funções e de métodos. Existem casos em que é necessário por implementações, mas você não faz uso desses casos.

Comment: Obrigado desde já pelas explicações, eu decidi voltar atrás e deixar tudo junto (apesar de me perder em tantos procedimentos xD), alguém tem dicas para organizar melhor o código?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não tens por aí por acaso um link que me ajude a ordenar uma linked list; pois não estou a conseguir ordena-la, tenho isto: prio_maior(){
 struct info *p;
 p=lista2;
 struct info *temp=NULL;
 struct info *j=NULL;
 
 while(p!=NULL){
  j=lista2;
  j=j->next;
 while(j!=NULL){
  if(p->nivel<=j->nivel){
   cout<<p->nivel;
   temp=p;
   p=j;
   j=temp;
   cout<<p->nivel;
   j=j->next;
 }else {
  j=j->next;
 }
 }p=p->next;
 
}}